# Resize Shared buffer size in Postgresql hosted in AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, rds

We are facing performance issue on Production Postgresql Database server which is hosted in AWS RDS server. So that we installed postgresql in EC2 instance Linux server  for pre-production  and tried with shared buffer value 15% of RAM value we get some positive response.

So that, Definitely we can assign shared buffer value 15% to 30 % of RAM value.
But when i trying to resize shared buffer value in Production DB server which i hosted in AWS RDS. it says invalid parameter value.
By default following value is assigned for shared buffer parameter.
 shared buffer = {DBInstanceClassMemory/32768}
Please help me to resize shared buffer value is min 15 % of RAM memory.
My Instance specification is : 2 CPU, 7.5 GB RAM (db.m3.large).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to set `shared_buffers` to 15% of RAM, put **147456** as value instead of `{DBInstanceClassMemory/32768}`...

`shared buffers` is set as number of 8kB blocks => calculating is such:

```
postgres=> select (15*7.5*1024*1024 /100)/8;
      ?column?
---------------------
 147456.000000000000
(1 row)
```

where:

- 15 is 15%
- 7.5 is 7.5 GB of RAM
- 1024*1024 to convert GB to KB (to unify against `shared_buffers` units
- 8 is 8kB

then you have to reboot your RDS instance and check value with:

`show shared_buffers;` in psql

Comment: I advise leaving the existing format and update the `32768` by `54613` (100/15*8*1024). It will be 15% even if you up or downgrade the instance class

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here, but wouldn't changing {DBInstanceClassMemory/32768} to {DBInstanceClassMemory/54613} change the percentage of cache memory available from 25% to 15% and therefore reduce database performance? Does the OP realize they're shrinking the cache?

Comment: I think I must be missing something obvious here, but why is DBInstanceClassMemory/32768 25% instead of, like 0.003%?